# Can't ping wireless laptop from internal network

Tags: windows-server-2003, networking, routing, wifi

If I connect a laptop wirelessly to my router it gets assigned an IP of 192.168.4.X. If I use a wired computer inside the same network (IP:192.168.2.X) I am not able to ping the laptop, but I am able to ping the gateway (IP:192.168.4.1).

The network is run using Windows Server 2003.

The firewall on the laptop is off. I have tried google, but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated on how I could connect to the laptop from a wired connection inside the network.

Thanks

Comment: What sort of router, any idea if that is blocking your pings..

Comment: You appear to have two seperate RFC1918 subnets there.  Are you sure that your router isn't trying to NAT between the two subnets?

Comment: Standard linksys router, I don't know if it is blocking my pings...How should I check that?

Comment: I logged into the router and am trying to find something that would disallow ping but have not found it. Any ideas?

Comment: No NAT settings are on the router

Comment: I assume you're trying to ping via IP and not by computer name? NetBIOS won't broadcast across multiple subnets unless the DHCP server specifies a specific common NetBIOS server.

Answer (score 2):

Your router most likely has two separate networks -- one for wired and the other wireless.  You can check the subnet mask as Alberto suggests, but if this was the case then your device would probably have the same default-gateway assuming you are using DHCP.

- The router may be configured to
  firewall the two networks from one another.
- Another cause of this behavior may be that the laptop has its own
  firewall enabled.  Do you have another wireless device you can test with?

Comment: I will attempt to find another wireless device to test with and let you know

Comment: The other laptop I found, running Ubuntu, responded the same way.

Comment: Can the two wireless devices ping each other?  Can they ping the internet? What does a traceroute to google look like from each of the networks?

Comment: I do not have either wireless devices right now. I remember trying a traceroute from one of the devices and its first path was to my server at 192.168.2.1 and then out to google, which is the same as from my wired device

Comment: That doesn't make sense that a wireless device in the 192.168.4.x range would have a first hop response from a 192.168.2.1 device unless that device has two NIC cards?  Going to need some additional details, perhaps a simple diagram to understand this issue better.

Answer (score 0):

What subnet mask are you using? Since the wired computer has 192.168.**2**.X and the laptop 192.168.**4**.X, if you are using the default `255.255.255.0` instead of `255.255.0.0` the router could be ignoring your requests since the computers won't be in the same network segment.

Comment: But I can ping the gateway at 192.168.4.1...

Comment: Try first the suggestions of Peter's answer, since I just get a new router yesterday and seems to have two subnets and he says. If it still won't work try using the same subnet for both wired and wireless (either put both devices at 192.168.2.X or change the subnet mask to 255.255.0.0.